# OSX: How can I change Command+D from "browse to desktop" to "browse to X" folder?"

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

OSX question here: My mental default, albeit lazy, way to save files is to <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, then when the "Save To" prompt comes up, <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to browse to the Desktop, then Save.

I'd like to use <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to open a different folder on my Desktop to hide the clutter.

How can I remap <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to browse to a different folder?

Answer (score 1):

[Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) allows adding custom shortcuts for folders (that will also be available in Finder).

[image]

Comment: Well, it sounds like it'll do the job, but $35 for just one hotkey swap? I'm ambivalent about the value of this utility.

Comment: @nipponese I'd never buy Default Folder X either, but someone had to mention it. I don't know any other apps like it. Or any way to change the folder with AppleScripts, other than to emulate pressing ⇧⌘G and typing the folder path.